# About Pandas .sample()

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe. i.e. 'df', it has 10,000 rows and 4 columns(one columns has values of "Yes/No" only named "purchased", 4,000 Yes and 6,000 No)

If I write this code:

```
sample = df.sample(df.shape[0], replace = True)
```

Then I assumed it will return me the whole dataframe with disordered. So I used .shape() and it turned out the sample has same number of records with df. (10,000)

Then I used

```
sample.query('purchased == "Yes"').info()
```

Now.....this time result confused me....each time I run it, the number of records given by info()....(2,333; 3000; 1540;.....)

Why is that? If the sample is just the whole df, shouldn't .info() be same every time? (4,000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in pandas documentation if you set the replace parameter to True it can add the same row several times so it is possible that the 'sample' variable contains a dataset different from the original with different number of rows with purchased value equals to "yes"

reference:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html